# AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute '' reverse connection

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm trying to implement reverse connection , but i get this error :

> 'admin':i.mobileinv_imei.invoice.seller.username,
> AttributeError: 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'invoice'

this is my models.py

```
class Imei(models.Model):
    mobile = models.ForeignKey(MobileCollection,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    imei = models.CharField(max_length=15,unique=True)
    status= models.BooleanField(default=True)

class ImeiInvoice(models.Model):  
    item = models.ForeignKey(Imei,on_delete=models.PROTECT,related_name='mobileinv_imei')
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(CustomerInvoice,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='invoice')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=3)

class CustomerInvoice(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mobiles = models.ManyToManyField(Imei,through='ImeiInvoice')
```

im trying to return seller name from `Imei` model, here is my views.py

```
def imei_sold_lists(request):
    imeis = Imei.objects.filter(status=False) 
    lists = []
    for i in imeis:
        imei = {            
            'admin':i.mobileinv_imei.invoice.seller.username,
            'customer':i.mobileinv_imei.invoice.customer,
            'imei':i.imei,
            'price':i.mobileinv_imei.price
         }
        lists.append(imei)    
    return JsonResponse({'data':lists})
```

is there something i've missed please? or should i change something please?
Thank you for helping ..

Comment: `i.mobileinv_imei` is a related manager. There could be multiple related `ImeiInvoice` objects so it doesn't make sense to access `invoice`, which related object would it return the invoice for?

Comment: @IainShelvington i want to access `ImeiInvoice` data from `Imei`

Answer (score 1):

`i.mobileinv_imei` is a `RelatedManager` for `ImeiInvoice`. It is not a singular `ImeiInvoice` object. You seem to be trying to use `ForeignKey` for a one-to-one relation when it is a many-to-one.

If you are sure that there are only one `ImeiInvoice` for that `Imei`, you can use

```py
i.mobileinv_imei.first().invoice
```

I don't know you use case, but, if you need to have a one-to-one relationship between all those models, I suggest you to use a nullable `Imei` -> `ImeiInvoice`":

```py
class Imei(models.Model):
    ...
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(blank=True, null=True, to=ImeiInvoice)
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but it returns `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'invoice'`

Comment: i want to access `ImeiInvoice` data from `Imei` model ! is it possible please

Comment: As I said, for `first()` to work, you should have related `Invoice` object. If you get `NoneType`, it means you don't.